# Find $nearSphere result with zero distance from queried point

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following record in my mongoDb:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e63313059484f212a4305f"),
    "title" : "The video title",
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.9667,
            40.78
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
}
```

I want to be able to find all the points at that *exact* location.
If I write:

```
db.videos.find({
  location: {
    '$nearSphere': {
      '$geometry': {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [-73.9667, 40.78]
      },
      '$maxDistance': 0
    }
  }
})[0]
```

I don't get any results. If I type:

```
db.videos.find({
  location: {
    '$nearSphere': {
      '$geometry': {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [-73.9667, 40.78]
      },
      '$maxDistance': 0.00001
    }
  }
})[0]
```

I get the one result.

I looked and looked, and nowhere in the docs say that maxDistance cannot be 0.

Can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as would make sense, [`$maxDistance`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/maxDistance/) set to `0` would be ignored just as if you had not set the option.

If you are looking for an "exact match" then just ask for that. It's not a `$nearSphere` query by any description:

```js
db.videos.find({
    "location.coordinates" : [ -73.9667, 40.78 ]
})
```

Which will of course return the document matching that "exact" location.

For something a little more complex, then use aggregation [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) instead. It projects a "distance" which you can use in later filtering:

```js
db.videos.aggregate([
    { "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [ -73.9667, 40.78 ]
        },
        "distanceField": "distance",
        "spherical": true
    }},
    { "$match": { "distance": 0 } }
])
```

So the intial pipeline stage returns a "distance" and the second stage filters out any results where that distance was in fact `0`.

You really only should need that if your queried objects were something like a "Polygon" or other GeoJSON form that would not match the "exact" coordinates array.

The general "exact" array match should suit for "Point" data.